# Architecture for nested form view in Backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, architecture, view, backbone-views

I'm new to Backbone.js and I'm developing a Backbone app, and have run into a bit of a dilemma concerning how to architecture my views.

Essentially what I want is this: a view that displays a list of models, with a form that animates on top of that list for creating a new model. The tricky thing is that I'd like the state in which my form appears to be a different route from the state with no form.

So I would like my application to look like this for the route `/`:

```
 _________________________________
|                                 |
|  - Item one                     |
|  - Item two                     |
|  - Item three                   |
|  - Item four                    |
|  - Item five                    |
|_________________________________|
```

And for the route `/new`:

```
 _________________________________
|                     |           |
|  - Item one         |  [Form]   |
|  - Item two         |           |
|  - Item three       |           |
|  - Item four        |           |
|  - Item five        |           |
|_____________________|___________|
```

Where the sidebar/form animates in and out as the user switches between these two states.

How would you suggest I deal with the architecture of these views/routes?

In my current, flawed implementation, I have one view to represent all of this (with the form hidden by css), The route `/new` triggers a jQuery animation to reveal the form. The problem is that `/new` relies on the user having visited `/` immediately before, as it relies on the view having been rendered in `/` already. Visiting this url directly is then broken, because the view has not yet been rendered.

The simple solution, as I see it, would be to have the list, and the list+form be two separate views. This seems inefficient, as the list would have to be re-constructed and rendered from scratch as a user navigated from `/` to `/new`, even though it was already on screen just fine. This re-rendering would also make animating between the two states impossible.

My gut tells me that there is an elegant, Backbonian solution to this problem, or at least an ugly one that gets the job done, without breaking the urls of my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at Backbone.js collections. The difference between the two views in the routes (/ and /new), from my understanding is, one has a extra form in the collection view.

Therefore what you can do is, use Backbone Models to represent and item and design it using view. Then use create a Backbone Collection [2] to wrap the model.

Then define two difference collection views for the same collection. [3] 
Using Backbone Routing, you can render the two difference collection views to those two URLs.

[2] http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

[3] http://rotundasoftware.github.io/backbone.collectionView/

Refer the following simple architecture view for the solution.

[image: Modular Architecture]